# CSS only Tool tip Need

Tags: html, css

I have tried to make a tooltip appear using CSS only. I have a solution; however I need another structure in my HTML, and remove the current use of a wrapper div.

This is my current HTML with a wrapper, that makes the div with class tooltip appear:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="1.png"></img>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <span>1. A small tooltip.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following css is what displays the tooltip:

```
.wrapper:hover > .tooltip {
  display:block;
}
```

Here is my code describing the problem; http://jsfiddle.net/5p3teu5b/15/.

How do I make the div `.tooltip` appear without the wrapper div?

Comment: @obsidian Thanks a ton. I need a small clarifications. Lot of restrictions i have. So please do the needful of above question

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Had a look at the fiddle, and it works, so also don't know what the problem is

Comment: @johan Its working. problem is i can't use the same structure of html. I need only the above structure. so can u tell me any changes on code

Comment: @qussama ELGOUMRI Its working. problem is i can't use the same structure of html. I need only the above structure. so can u tell me any changes on code

Answer (score 2):

You can use another selector than "child of", [see the fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/tk3d9q3z/). If you want the sibling to the image to display when hovering, you can use the `+` selector, described at [W3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors).

so your HTML will look like this, notice the extra class on the img tag.

```
<div>
    <img class="sibling" src="1.png"></img>
    <div class="tooltip">
        <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following css

```
.sibling:hover + .tooltip {
    display:block;
}
.tooltip{
    display: none;
}
```

This will make the div with class `tooltip` appear when you hover an image with class `sibling`, but only if it appears directly after it. If you want all siblings with the class `.tooltip` to appear when hovering any image, you can use `img:hover + .tooltip` as a selector instead.